# Check if GPS and/or Mobile Network location is enabled

Tags: java, android, gps, locationmanager

Im trying to check whether GPS and/or WiFi & Mobile network location are located. My current codes simply works for just GPS, and I've attempted to try to include the network provider, however i've getting the following error.

First Error

`The method isProviderEnabled(String) in the type LocationManager is not applicable for the arguments (String, String)`

---

Current Code

```
    if (locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER)){
            Toast.makeText(this, "GPS is Enabled in your device", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }else{
            displayAlert();
        }
```

---

Comment: Any reason you aren't using the new [Fused Location provider](https://developer.android.com/google/play-services/location.html)? It gives a location much faster, is more power-efficient, and combines all of the providers together.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to check each provider separately:

```
if (locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER) ||
    locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER)){
        Toast.makeText(this, "GPS/Network is Enabled in your device", 
            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }else{
        displayAlert();
    }
```

Comment: It says you have a null pointer at org.greenbot.technologies.gpsme.MainActivity.<init>(MainActivity.java:30) - what is that line?

Answer (score 1):

If you see documentation of [isProvideEnabled(String)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html#isProviderEnabled%28java.lang.String%29), only one String is allowed as parameter. So you can do the checking seperately:

```
boolean gpsPresent = locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
boolean networkProviderPresent = locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
```

Then you can check them as @ianhanniballake said or something like:

```
if ( (!gpsPresent) && (!networkProviderPresent) ){
     displayAlert(); // Nothing is available to give the location
}else {
    if (gpsPresent){
        Toast.makeText(this, "GPS is Enabled in your device", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();    
    }
    if (networkProviderPresent ){
        Toast.makeText(this, "Network Provider is Present on your device", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();   
    }
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: isProviderEnabled() returns `IllegalArgumentException` if provider is null. At what line does it show null pointer exception though?

Comment: Its the line that the first `boolean gpsPresent`

Comment: can you post the LogCat if possible?